# Calculating Grade Point Average and Class Average in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, average

I am working on a problem that calls for me to compute the grade point average for each student in a class.

The input is a lisp file with the following format:

```
( ((name studentname) (class hour grade) (class hour grade) ...)
((name studentname) (class hour grade) (class hour grade) ...) ...)
```

For the output: I need to print the students name and their GPA (average of the grades for that student) sorted by average grade as well as the class average (the average of the grades for each unique class).

So far this is what I have

```
(setq class '(((name Seymore) (eng 3 4.0) (mat 3 3.0) (his 3 4.0) (bio 3 2.0) (biol 1 4.0))
 ((name Ichahbod) (cs 3 3.0) (mat 3 4.0) (spe 2 4.0) (che 3 4.0) (chel 1 3.0) (lit 3 3.0))
 ((name Zackery) (mat 5 3.0) (eng 3 3.0) (jou 2 3.0) (phy 3 3.0) (phyl 1 4.0) (lit 2 4.0))
 ((name Tukerville) (soc 4 3.0) (mus 2 4.0) (jou 3 4.0) (geo 4 4.0) (geol 1 3.0) (eng 3 3.0))
 ((name Simonsays) (css 3 3.0) (ast 3 4.0) (spe 3 4.0) (cs 3 4.0) (spe 2 3.0) (dan 4 4.0))
 ((name Snicker) (eng 3 4.0) (phy 4 4.0) (css 3 2.0) (csl  1 4.0) (ped 2 3.0) (mat 3 3.0))
 ((name Glass) (mat 3 1.0) (eng 3 1.0) (ped 1 1.0) (bio 3 1.0) (biol 1 0.0) (che 3 1.0) (chel 1 1.0))))

;this function multiplies the hours * the grades
(defun product (hours grades)
   (* hours grades)
)

;this function multiplies a set of grades
(defun sumofGrades (L)
    (cond
       ((null L) 0) ;check if it is first
       (t (+ (product (cdr (cdadar L)) (caddar L)))) ;first val then the second val
       (sumofGrades (cdr L)) ;the rest of one
    )
)

;to get the total , same as sum of grades but sum the second variables
(defun totalHours (L) 
    (cond
       ((null L) 0) ;check if it is first
       (t (+ (product (caddar L) (caddar L)))) ;first val then the second val
       (totalHours() (cdr L)) ;the rest of one
    )
 )


(defun gradepoint (L)
   ( / (sumofGrades L) (totalHours L))
)
```

I attempted to start with the auxiliary methods because I thought that would be the best approach, it might not have been. When I run sumofGrades, I get back the 4.0 like I need from the first entry but it says it is not a number. I wrote these methods going off of the basic math that i need to do with the numbers but at this point I am confused on what to do next.

If I need to rewind and go a different routine I am down, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: next time please paste full error messages and function invocations.

Comment: okay, will do sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

**Your code**

```
(defun sumofGrades (L)
  (cond
   ((null L) 0) ;check if it is first
   (t (+ (product (cdr (cdadar L)) (caddar L)))) ;first val then the second val
   (sumofGrades (cdr L)) ;the rest of one
   )
  )
```

**Let's look at it**:

```
(defun sumofGrades (L)    ; please no camelCase in Lisp

  (cond


   ((null L) 0) ;check if it is first    <-  what does this comment mean???


   (t (+ (product (cdr (cdadar L)) (caddar L))))

   ;  what is (+ (product (cdr (cdadar L)) (caddar L))) ?
   ;  you are calling + with one argument. Why?

   ;  what does a function like caddar mean?
   ;  what is it supposed to do?
   ;  no one reading your code will have an idea why
   ;    caddar and not cdaadar, cdadaadr, or cdddddr...
   ;  write better documented, or self-documenting code.


   (sumofGrades (cdr L)) ;the rest of one    <- what does this comment mean?

   ; what is (sumofGrades (cdr L)) ?
   ; is   sumofGrades  a variable checked in COND?
   ; should it be a function call?
   ; just as it is alone here, it does not make any sense.
   ; since T is always true, this clause is also never reached...

   )    ;  <-  please no dangling parentheses in Lisp
  )
```

When compiling the above function, LispWorks says:

```
; (TOP-LEVEL-FORM 0)
;;;*** Warning in SUMOFGRADES: The following cond clause
;;;    will never be processed: ((SUMOFGRADES (CDR L)))
```

**Summary**: `sumofGrades` won't work. A Lisp compiler already complains about it.

---

**More about style**

Global variables: they are defined by DEFPARAMETER or DEFVAR. Don't use `SETQ`.

Don't write

```
(setq class ...)
```

instead write:

```
(defparameter *class* ...
   "the global variable *class* is a list of ...")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was using cdadar, cdr and other functions to obtain the grade an hours from the different lists. I wanted to essentially grab the individual numbers and add them, them multiply them to get the product. My professor helped some with this code so I was feeding off him. I am VERY new to lisp so I apologize for the syntax quirks.

Comment: @user2762848: the problem is that you will never remember what CADAR means. If it means GET-HOURS, then use a function GET-HOURS instead.  If it means something else, then name that something else. But give it a useful name. You may need to write it...

Answer (score 3):

First define some generic average function:

```
(defun average (lst &key (key #'identity)) 
  (when lst
    (/ (reduce #'+ lst :key key) (length lst))))
```

Define also a grade function to retrieve the grade of a given student in a given class (not necessary but will make it more clear):

```
(defun grade (class) (caddr class))
```

and a grades function to retrieve the grades of a student:

```
(defun grades (student) 
    (cdr (find student class :key #'cadar)))
```

Now you can find the average of the grades of a student by calling

```
(average (grades 'seymore ) :key #'grade) 
=> 3.4
```

Following this example, you should be able to write the average of all the class by yourself.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much for your help. This helped a ton.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to try [`reduce`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm):

```
(mapcar (lambda (l) 
          (cons (second (first l)) 
                (/ (reduce #'+ (rest l) :key #'third)
                   (1- (length l)))))
        class)
==> 
((SEYMORE . 3.4) (ICHAHBOD . 3.5) (ZACKERY . 3.3333333) (TUKERVILLE . 3.5)
 (SIMONSAYS . 3.6666667) (SNICKER . 3.3333333) (GLASS . 0.85714287))
```

then you can sort this using [`sort`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sort_.htm):

```
(sort * #'< :key #'cdr)
==>
((GLASS . 0.85714287) (ZACKERY . 3.3333333) (SNICKER . 3.3333333) (SEYMORE . 3.4)
 (ICHAHBOD . 3.5) (TUKERVILLE . 3.5) (SIMONSAYS . 3.6666667))
```

here [`*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v__stst_.htm) is the value of the previous expression.

PS. Since this is probably h/w, I am giving a code sample rather than a complete solution, I suggest that you play with my code and then ask another very specific question if something is not unclear.

PPS. A few stylistic remarks:

1. do not define functions like your `product`, it's just confusing noise
2. do not use the CamelCase, use normal-lisp-dashes instead
3. do not use hanging parens
4. use Emacs to indent your code, it is unreadable now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I am very new to lisp and this helped a lot. I correcting my code with your suggestions and will notify you if i have a question. Thank you again.